# Full-point-losing move in an endgame rook vs rook?

Tags: blunder, rook-endgame

Does anyone know a game, where a full-point-losing move was made in an endgame
 where each side had only one rook and pawns ?

Comment: You've asked a fair number of questions about extremely specific positions. I'm a little curious on where this is all leading. whasssupp?

Comment: My object is to improve my endgame skills. Why not study the errors of the great players in order to do this ? And why not study special endgames deeper in order to do this ?

Comment: That's what I was curious about.

Comment: What does "full-point-losing" mean? 1 point of computer evaluation? Going from drawn to lost? Going from won to lost? I realize now that I may have answered this question and your analogous one about pawn endgames incorrectly.

Comment: With "full-point-losing" I mean a losing move in a  won position. Since examples with upto 6 pieces probably do not exist, I will accept computer evaluations, if the PLY is high enough.

Comment: What will be more frequent : That a winning position is eventually lost. First search such an example.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've removed my previous answers and comments that were based on a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example between two super grandmasters:

```
[White "Laurent Fressinet"]
[Black "Vladimir Malakhov"]
[Event "FIDE World Cup 2013"]
[Site "Tromso"]
[Date "2013.08.16"]
[FEN "8/2r5/8/6R1/3k1Pp1/6P1/2K5/8 w - - 4 59"]

1.Kb3 $4 ( 1.Kb2 $1 { The only winning move. } Rb7+ 2.Ka3 Kc4 ( 2...Ra7+ { Continuing to check like this isn't useful, as the king just walks towards the rook. } 3.Kb4 Rb7+ 4.Ka5 Ra7+ 5.Kb6 ) 3.Rxg4 { The win with the connected passed pawns is still a bit tricky, as White's king is badly placed. What follows is a sample line. } Rb5 4.Rg6 Rf5 5.Ka4 Kd4 6.Kb4 Ke4 7.Kc4 Ra5 8.Re6+ Kf3 9.Re5 Ra1 10.Rg5 Ke4 11.Kb5 Rc1 12.Rc5 Rg1 13.Re5+ Kf3 14.Rg5 Ke4 15.Kc6 Rd1 16.Re5+ Kf3 17.Rd5 Rf1 18.Rg5 Rd1 19.f5 Ke4 20.g4 Ke5 21.Rg6 Rd2 22.Re6+ Kf4 23.Rd6 Rf2 24.Rg6 Rd2 25.f6 Ke5 26.g5 Ke6 27.Rg7 Rc2+ 28.Kb7 Rf2 29.Kc8 Rf1 30.Re7+ Kf5 31.Kd8 Ra1 32.Rd7 Kg6 33.f7 Kg7 34.Ke8 Ra8+ 35.Ke7 Rb8 36.g6 Kxg6 37.f8=Q Rxf8 38.Kxf8 ) 1...Rc3+ 2.Kb4 Rxg3 3.Rg8 Ke4 4.Kc4 Rg2 5.Re8+ Kxf4 6.Kd3 Ra2 7.Rf8+ Kg3 8.Ke3 Kg2 0-1
```

White has a won position here, but must play Kb2.  Instead he played Kb3, which loses to Rc3+. (I have generated a FinalGen tablebase to confirm the status of the positions. The Lomonosov tablebases could be used instead, but I don't have access to them.)